# Match two columns and return values based on a condition in two other columns

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, conditional-statements, return-value

Four total columns: Column A **Part#**, Column B **Old Cost**, Column C **Part#**, Column D **New Cost**

I need to match the two Part# columns (they are the same part numbers in a different order):

Once matched, compare the accompanying two columns of Costs

If the costs match, return **MATCHED**

If the costs are different, return the New Cost amount

```
Col A Part#    Col B Old Price  Col C Part #     Col D New Price**
5555           $5.00              1111           $1.00 
4444           $4.00              2222           $2.99 
1111           $1.00              3333           $3.00 
2222           $2.00              4444           $4.99 
3333           $3.00              5555           $5.99 
8888           $8.00              6666           $6.99 
7777           $7.00              7777           $7.99 
9999           $9.00              8888           $8.99 
6666           $6.00              9999           $9.99
```

An example return:

```
Part# 1111  MATCH
Part# 2222  $2.99
Part# 7777  $7.99
Part# 3333  MATCH
```

Comment: Vlookup will do this.  compare the result of the vlookup to the other value.  If you want more specifics, please mock up some data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use VLOOKUP and compare the results:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(G2,A:B,2,FALSE)=VLOOKUP(G2,C:D,2,FALSE),"MATCH",VLOOKUP(G2,C:D,2,FALSE))
```

[image]